# PHP | how to check if some data is present in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter, Yes i have searched internet and i have `in_array()` but it seems that it is not working.

See here is the array i am getting from database.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/dashboard/System ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/dashboard/Users ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/residentials/# ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/configurations/# ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/configurations/ManageForms ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/residentials/Houses ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/residentials/Flats ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/configurations/ManageTabs ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/configurations/SitePreferences ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/usersManageUsers/# ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/usersManageUsers/CreateUser ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [FormCIPath] => admin/usersManageUsers/ListUsers ) )
```

i want to find if `configurations/ManageForms` is present inside the array, so i tried like this.

```
$partialURI = $class."/".$method;
if(in_array($partialURI,$result)){
    return "True";
}
else{
    return "FALSE";
}
```

but i always get False in return. i haved checked the variable `$partialURI` it is returning `configurations/ManageForms`.
But still i am getting FALSE in return and where as you can see this text is present inside array above??

Comment: why cant you use in_array() ?

Comment: @AvinashBabu
its an object array, thats why i guess `in_array()` didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `in_array()` works only on flat, you could just use a simple foreach loop:

```
$partialURI = $class."/".$method;
foreach($result as $r) {
    if(stripos($r->FormCIPath, $partialURI) !== false) {
        return 'true';
    }
}
return 'false';
```

Comment: It looks to be an object array (if I'm correct) this might not work?

Comment: @DarylGill since each copy of the array inside is an object `$r->FormCIPath` just use the arrow operator, and just use stripos since your comparing `configurations/ManageForms` == `admin/configurations/ManageForms`

Comment: There we go :) forced a slight explanation out of you as to the logic behind your resolution

Comment: @DarylGill lol! no i don't feel forced actually glad i could clarify more

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data= new array ();
foreach ($result as $r) {

$data[]=$r;

}
```

Now try your code by replacing `$result` array with `$data`

```
$partialURI = $class."/".$method;
    if(in_array($partialURI,$data)){
                return "True";
            }
            else{
                return "FALSE";
            }
```